# Dynamic Change label value with global variabel tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

With this code I want to make label L3 and L4 change dynamically according to global variabel LED 1 and LED 2, but cant make it work with my code below, anyone have good suggestion for me?
I know it wont work because method init just running once every time I start run my code.
I read some suggestion before using root.after but I cant make it work with my code.

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from ttk import *
suhu=30
cahaya=50
LED1='-'
LED2='-'
def mqttx():
    def on_message(mqttc,obj,msg):
        global LED1
        global LED2
        print "Telah Diterima message : "+msg.payload+" topik "+msg.topic
        r.rpush(msg.topic,msg.payload)
        datasuhu = r.lrange("suhu",-1,-1)
        datacahaya = r.lrange("cahaya",-1,-1)
        if msg.topic=="suhu":
            if float(msg.payload)<=suhu :
                mqttc.publish("2","1",qos=0,retain=False)
                LED1="ON"

            elif float(msg.payload)>suhu:
                mqttc.publish("2","0",qos=0,retain=False)
                LED1="OFF"
        if msg.topic=="cahaya" :
            if float(msg.payload) <=cahaya:
                mqttc.publish("1","1",qos=0,retain=False)
                LED2="ON"
            elif float(msg.payload)>cahaya:
                mqttc.publish("1","0",qos=0,retain=False)
                LED2="OFF"


    mqttc.on_message =  on_message
    mqttc.connect("localhost",1883)
    mqttc.subscribe("suhu")
    mqttc.subscribe("cahaya")

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("Subcriber")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


        self.L3 =Label(self,text="LED 1 : "+LED1)
        self.L3.pack
        self.L3.grid()
        self.L4 =Label(self,text="LED 2 : "+LED2)
        self.L4.pack
        self.L4.grid()



def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mqttx()
    mqttc.loop_start()
    main()
```

Comment: That's too much code for this question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: use `self.L3['text'] = "new text"` to change text in label.

Comment: You can use `StringVar` for LED1 and LED2 and then associate them to the `textvariable` of L3 and L4 respectively.

Comment: @acw1668 already tried with that but not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `after()` to call function which will change text in labels.

I created `test()` function to test it without function `mqttx()`

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from ttk import *

LED1 = '-'
LED2 = '-'

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

        # run first time
        self.update()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("Subcriber")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.L3 = Label(self,text="LED 1 : "+LED1)
        self.L3.grid()
        self.L4 = Label(self, text="LED 2 : "+LED2)
        self.L4.grid()

    def update(self):
        #print('[DEBUG] update_text')

        self.L3['text'] = "LED 1 : " + LED1
        self.L4['text'] = "LED 2 : " + LED2

        # run again after 500ms (0.5s)
        self.after(500, self.update)


def test(root):
    import random    
    global LED1
    global LED2

    print('[DEBUG] test')
    LED1 = str(random.randint(1,10))
    LED2 = str(random.randint(1,10))

    # run again after 500ms (0.5s)
    root.after(500, test, root)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    test(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```